# knn compare 2 images matlab

Tags: matlab, knn

I need a help. I don't know how to write a Matlab/Java code compare 2 images using KNN, the result should take "wrong" when image 2 is different than image 1. I have to imporve displacement between x1,x2,x3 and that each subsequent generated image with the same x1,x2,x3 is invalid (Prove that the diameter has increased). Others compare it with histograms. Anybody will help me?

[image]

Comment: Your question is really unclear, if you only want to compare two images why would you use a KNN algorithm ?

Comment: KNN is not the right approach for finding similarity of data.  KNN is a **classification** algorithm.  You want actual image comparison algorithms.  Please refer to the above duplicates.

Comment: @obchardon because I have to imporve displacement between x1,x2,x3 and that each subsequent generated image is invalid.

Comment: @rayryeng  I have to imporve displacement between x1,x2,x3 and that each subsequent generated image with the same x1,x2,x3 is invalid.